# Log all requests made to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudtrail

I would like to debug an issue with DynamoDB.
`The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item`

For that I'd like to log all requests made to a DynamoDB Table from AWS (not from the lambda code).
I have the RequestId in the error and I wish to be able to search for it to find the exact requests with its parameters.

I have looked into AWS Cloudtrail but it seems to only log `Management Operations` not all gets and all puts done to DynamoDB.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think DynamoDB Streams will help you as it won't include failed API requests afaik. You should be able to enable a logger for most of the AWS SDKs so that might help log your API requests. Or simply add explicit tracing/logging prior to all PutItem requests in your application(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add this level of data plane logging to your application as currently CloudTrail only supports logging of control plane operations for DynamoDB.